# PHP includes Statement

Tags: php, include

I was wondering how include worked. i thought it was making 2 files or more into one big file

for example file 1 includes file 2. file 1 is in the root directory while file 2 is in root/include/file2.
 so if file 2 needed to include something from the root/include directory then instead of putting include("file3.php"); i would need to put include("root/include/file3.php"); 
so then all 3 files are considered by the server to be one big file.

am i anywhere close to how it actually is?

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP manual:

> Files are included based on the
>   file path given or, if none is given,
>   the include_path specified. The
>   include() construct will emit a
>   warning if it cannot find a file; this
>   is different behavior from require(),
>   which will emit a fatal error.
>
> If a path is defined (full or
>   relative), the include_path will be
>   ignored altogether. For example, if a
>   filename begins with ../, the parser
>   will look in the parent directory to
>   find the requested file.

So if you dont want to worry about specifying the relative paths set your [include path](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to /root/include. You can then just use

```
include("filename");
```

in any file. I'd also suggest looking at the function require() as it throws a fatal error if it cannot open the file.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it
> contains inherits the variable scope
> of the line on which the include
> occurs.

So the interactions between include files depends entirely on what scope you include them with one another.  Paths can be given that are full or relative or can be omitted in deference to the [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Answer (score 0):

include gets the contents of a file and puts it in the place you inserted the include statement.

It is important to note that **the included file is previously parsed by the PHP interpreter**,
so you can do things such as

> if ( ! @include() ) { echo 'the user edited file has a syntax error, default restored.') }

Comment: There are actually two circumstances in which include returns false: (1) The include fails or (2) The included file has a return statement in the global scope, which returns a false value.  For example, the code you provided would result in a false positive, if the included file consisted of "<?php return false; ?>"

Comment: You are right and I know it.  It is not a false positive, it has to be considered as a feature, not a bug. The included script can deliberately return FALSE just to make its including script know that something was wrong, not being necessary to have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What `include` does is it pastes one file into another.

Say you have `a.php`:

```
Hello,
```

And `b.php`:

```
world!
```

Then `c.php`:

```
<?php include "a.php"; include "b.php"; ?>
```

Will become:

```
Hello, world!
```

When parsed by PHP. PHP does some magic stuff, but this is the basic effect.

If you need to use a file from another directory (like "hello/world.php"), you have to use that full relative path, not just the file name.

Comment: OK so if include many documents into one it will appear as one. but what is the restriction of including more than one document. 

what im traying to ask is what does 
"the included file is previously parsed by the PHP interpreter"
mean exactly. does it mean i cant cary variables from one document to the included document.

for example index.php includes var.php which contains the database conection variables(like username host and password). index.php also includes connect.php which opens the database conection. index php also has a mysql statment to pull data from the database and display .

Comment: You *can* carry variables, etc. between documents - another answer comments that new code inherits the variable scope of the old one, that means that they act like they're the same document.